# Read input from console in OSX

Tags: c, xcode, macos, console, terminal

I'm using `scanf()` to read user input on terminal in a console application. scanf waits until the user hits the return key to read. Is there a way to read the user input on each keystroke?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way would be to use the [`getch`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) function from (the Mac port of) [ncurses](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/ncurses/Portfile).

Note that while `getchar` reads a single character, it still normally does buffered reading, so you need to press 'return'/'enter' before it'll return.

Answer (score 3):

`getch()` returns the character stream from stdin as it is typed.

Comment: That would be very unusual - it is not the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = getchar();
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: why ? he wants a `char` - and an `int` takes more memory

Comment: with int you can check for out-of-band values, also, when declared as local variable it will probably take the same place.

Comment: @Quantic: getchar() returns an int, so it can return any normal char as well as a non-char value like EOF.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what 'out-of-band' values mean - please explain

Comment: There are values that does not fit in `char` (as @Rudy Velthuis said) and you cannot detect them when you use a char.

Comment: EOF is a value different from any valid `char` - so you can't reliably store the result of `getchar()` in a `char` because it can return any valid `char` and EOF.